# How to add dll to the project in MinGW Developer Studio

Tags: c++, dll, header, mingw

I have a project which main starts like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL\glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "struktury.h"

#define YS 1.0f
#define PI 3.1415
```

I also have `glut.dll` file. The project directory looks like that:
[image]

I have no idea how to add a dll file to this project in MINGW Developer Studio, also I do not have this `GL/glut.h` file. Please help me I am exhausted by this.

[image]